# Multiple update statements in postgres CTE

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I am experiencing a strange problem with a CTE expression containing multiple update statements.

I can reproduce with the following SQL:-

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS foo;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS baa;
CREATE TABLE foo(id BIGSERIAL, attributes JSONB);
CREATE TABLE baa(id BIGSERIAL, attributes JSON );
INSERT  INTO foo(attributes) SELECT jsonb_build_object('foo', 'baa');

WITH STEP_ONE AS (

    UPDATE foo 
    SET attributes = attributes ||jsonb_build_object('foo2', 'baa2')
    WHERE id = 1
    RETURNING attributes->>'foo' AS foo_att,id

), STEP_TWO AS (
    INSERT INTO baa(attributes)
    SELECT json_build_object('foo', id)
    FROM STEP_ONE
    RETURNING id as baa_id
) 
UPDATE foo
  SET attributes = attributes ||jsonb_build_object('baa', baa_id)
  FROM STEP_TWO
  WHERE id = 1
```

This will not update table foo. But replacing the final update with "SELECT * FROM STEP_TWO" shows records are present.

Is this a bug in postgresql? Or am I missing something in the documentation concerning updating a single table more than once in a CTE?

Postgres Version:

```
PostgreSQL 11.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this [is documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

> All the statements are executed with the same *snapshot* (see [Chapter 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html)), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables.

You'll either have to rewrite the query so that each table is modified only once in the statement, or you have to run two separate statements.

Comment: Thanks I'd read this but misinterpreted "sub-statements" as being anything enclosed in AS() and clearly the final statement counts as well